# What is the right way to use the `do` notation with Agda-stdlib's IO?

Tags: agda

I'm trying to use the `do-notation` together with `IO` from `agda-stdlib`, but, strangely, the type of `_>>_` uses `∞`: `{B : Set a} (m₁ : ∞ (IO B)) (m₂ : ∞ (IO A)) → IO A`. Because of that, I need to interleave `♯`s between applications, but this makes the usage awkward. For example, `♯`s are necessary to build a program that prints a line:

```
main : IO ⊤
main = do
  ♯ (putStrLn "hi")
  ♯ (return tt)
```

Moreover, extending it with more lines fail to check. I have to abandon the `do-notation`, like this:

```
main : IO ⊤
main = 
  ♯ (♯ putStrLn "hi" >> 
    ♯ putStrLn "ho") >>
    ♯ return tt
```

Which looks terrible. I could redefine `_>>_` and `_>>=_`:

```
_>>_ : {A : Set} {B : Set} (m₁ : (IO B)) (m₂ : (IO A)) → IO A
_>>_ a b = (♯ a) IO.>> (♯ b)
```

But I'm assuming that's not what I'm expected to do. So, am I missing something? What is the proper way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `IO` in the standard library predates the addition of `do`-notation in Agda, so it was not written with `do`-notation in mind. Ulf's [Agda prelude](https://github.com/UlfNorell/agda-prelude/blob/master/src/Prelude/IO.agda) has a more up-to-date implementation of `IO` that does support `do`-notation.